# Position independent code in NASM (32bit)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

How can I simply call an external symbol in a library function written in 32bit x86 assembler? This works under x86-64 (NASM):

```
extern ExternSymbol

MyFunc:
    ...
    call ExternSymbol WRT ..plt
```

The same code compiled for 32bit x86 jumps to address 0x0.

Comment: I think that's pretty much it what you have there, I suspect you are actually asking how to link it together with that library containing that symbol. For that, compile your .asm to your favorite object file (i think that would be -f win32 for instance) and then link it with link.exe or ld or whatever..

Comment: I've found the problem. I have to prepare a pointer to GOT in ebx.

Answer (score 2):

You must be doing something wrong, as it works for me like this:

```
$ cat >libfoo.c
int foo() { return 42; }
$ gcc -m32 -shared -o libfoo.so libfoo.c
$ cat >main.asm
[bits 32]
extern foo
global _start
_start:
call foo wrt ..plt
mov ebx, eax
mov eax, 1
int 80h
$ nasm -f elf32 main.asm
$ gcc -nostdlib -m32 -L. -lfoo main.o
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./a.out
$ echo $?
42
```